# Torch sum each row excluding an index

Tags: matrix, sum, pytorch, tensor

Given a Tensor A of shape (N,C) and an indices Tensor Idx of shape (N,), i'd like to sum all the elements of each row in A excluding the corresponding column index in I. For example:

```
A = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6]])

Idx = torch.tensor([0,2])

#result:
torch.tensor([[5],
              [9]])
```

A solution using loops is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set excluded elements to zero:

```
A[range(A.shape[0]),Idx] = 0
```

and sum tensor along rows:

```
b = A.sum(dim = 1,keepdim = True ) # b = torch.tensor([[5],  [9]])
```